# Unable to get session from session store

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I have read and copy pasted a lot of examples on using sessions with socket.io, express and a session store. However, every time I call `sessionStore.get()` (or `sessionStore.load()`) all I get back is `undefined`. Why?

Here's my code (simplified):

```
var app = require('express')(),
    session = require('session'),    
    MongoStore = require('connect-mongostore')(session);

app.use(session({
    store: new MongoStore({ 'db': 'sessions' });
}));

io.use(function(socket, next) {
    var req = socket.request,
        reqCookie = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie),
        sessid = reqCookie['connect.sid']; // == actual session ID

    sessionStore.get(sessid, function(err, session) {
        err // == undefined
        session // == undefined
    });
    next() ;
});
```

I also tried with `session.MemoryStore` in stead of `connect-mongostore`, with the same result. I modified 
`node_modules/express-session/session/memory.js` to try and log out the sessions in the sessionStore:

```
MemoryStore.prototype.get = function(sid, fn){
  var self = this;    
  console.log(self.sessions); // Output: {}
```

I'm a newbie when it comes to sessions and such, so thank you for bearing with me.

**Update:** I have tried the code on two different systems and networks, but I still get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally figured out how to solve this. It turns out that the session id returned from socket ios `socket.request.headers.cookie` is not entirely identical to the session id returned from nodejs' `req.sessionID`.

Here's how I get the session id in both cases, and an example of what they return.

Normal http request

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    req.sessionID; // == LMKJxTssmDgf8IxwijbC9G6LtDBuTQWX

});
```

Socket.io

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {

    var req = socket.request;

    if (req.headers.cookie) {
        req.cookie = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie);

        req.cookie['express.sid']; // == s:LMKJxTssmDgf8IxwijbC9G6LtDBuTQWX.ApVkBxAEf4o3Pdgo0PWDRHi+GvBaSdcK7q1pO4xslZ0
```

As you can see, the session id is there in both cases, we just have to delete some stuff on the one socket.io gives us. **Solution:** `req.cookie['express.sid'].split('.')[0].split(':')[1];`.